# How to unzip file in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I was trying to unzip a zip file, stored in Hadoop file system, & store it back in hadoop file system. I tried following commands, but none of them worked.

```
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/test.zip|gzip -d|hadoop fs -put - /tmp/
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/test.zip|gzip -d|hadoop fs -put - /tmp
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/test.zip|gzip -d|hadoop put - /tmp/
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/test.zip|gzip -d|hadoop put - /tmp
```

I get errors like `gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored`, `cat: Unable to write to output stream.`, `Error: Could not find or load main class put` on terminal, when I run those commands. Any help?

**Edit 1**: I don't have access to UI. So, only command lines are allowed. Unzip/gzip utils are installed on my hadoop machine. I'm using `Hadoop 2.4.0` version.

Comment: AFAIK, the only vanilla way to do so would be to get the file of your local machine, unzip it and send it back to the cluster.

Comment: I don't have that liberty :|

Comment: Have you considered [this solution ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256808/unzip-files-using-hadoop-streaming)

Comment: As a side note, have you tried replacing `-cat` by `-text` ?

Comment: @fxm None of them worked. `-text` gave `gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored` error :|

Comment: man gzip: "Files created by zip can be uncompressed by gzip only if they have a single member compressed with the ’deflation’ method.". normally you can't use gzip -d or gunzip to decompress zip files. those commands are for gzip/tar-gzip files only. that's why you got "gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored" error.

Answer (score 8):

To unzip a gzipped (or bzipped) file, I use the following

```
hdfs dfs -cat /data/<data.gz> | gzip -d | hdfs dfs -put - /data/
```

If the file sits on your local drive, then

```
zcat <infile> | hdfs dfs -put - /data/
```

Answer (score 2):

I use most of the times hdfs fuse mounts for this

So you could just do

```
$ cd /hdfs_mount/somewhere/
$ unzip file_in_hdfs.zip
```

http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_28.html

Edit 1/30/16: In case if you use hdfs ACLs: In some cases fuse mounts don't adhere to hdfs ACLs, so you'll be able to do file operations that are permitted by basic unix access privileges. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6255, comments at the bottom that I recently asked to reopen.

Comment: I use this for files with hundreds of Gb in size. Performance-wise - it has to be tested vs other options you may have, if any. It's just so much more convenient - just run gunzip.

Comment: Just curious, Isn't similar to copying to local and then copying back?

Comment: Do you mean hadoop fs -get; unzip; hadoop fs -put ? I don't see how it is similar as you may need huge local disk just to be able to do that. Also, that requires three steps, while Answer above I suggested with hdfs fuse mount is just one simple step.

Comment: Yes, I meant get/put thing. Thanks for clarifying it. Let me give it a try and get back to you :)

Comment: So this deserves to be the answer for "How to unzip file in hadoop?" question? Doesn't look there are other options.

Answer (score 0):

To stream the data through a pipe to hadoop, you need to use the hdfs command.

```
cat mydatafile | hdfs dfs -put - /MY/HADOOP/FILE/PATH/FILENAME.EXTENSION
```