# Zip/Unzip files on HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, zip, hdfs, object-storage

I have my code deployed on HDFS and have two basic tasks, I am having trouble figuring out -

1. fetching a zip file from an ObjectStore to HDFS, **unzipping it on HDFS**, reading it's contents, deleting the zip and contents.
2. creating some content on HDFS, **zipping it on HDFS**, posting it to ObjectStore and then deleting the zip.

Regular libraries for zipping/unzipping in a python script like shutil, etc do not work on HDFS URLs when referring to resources. I tried looking up some python libraries that would allow it, but found none.

The closest solution I got to was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256808/unzip-files-using-hadoop-streaming) but it came with a fair warning of not working when multiple files are zipped together. Can someone help with a pointer to the solution to the tasks mentioned above in bold?